# Como fazer uma mensagem de carregamento enquanto uma Promisse carrega?

Tags: javascript, promises, requisição

Criei um arquivo js com o seguinte código:

```
function buscarRepos(){
    lista.innerHTML = '';
    var nomeUser = document.querySelector('div#app input').value;

   var resultado = minhaPromise(nomeUser)
   .then(function(response) {
        for (let url = 0; url < response.length; url++){
            resultado = response[url].html_url;

            var itemList = document.createElement('li');
            itemList.append(resultado);

            lista.append(itemList);
        }
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
     console.warn(error);
   });

   console.log(resultado);
}

var minhaPromise = function(username){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`);
        xhr.send(null);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xhr.readyState == 4){
                if (xhr.status == 200){
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                } else {
                    reject("Erro na requisição");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Agora preciso que enquanto o resultado dessa Promise carregue, apareça uma mensagem assim no html:

`<li>Carregando...</li>`

Como faço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode por quando a função for chamada:

```js
 lista.innerHTML = '<li>Carregando...</li>';
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.

Comment: Certo, sou novo no site, não sabia desse recurso. Passarei a usá-lo de hoje em diante.